# iTunes API - How to tell if a song is available on Apple Music?

Tags: ios, itunes

Apple recently updated the iTunes Affiliate API to redirect all links to Apple Music by default (https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/apple-music-is-now-live-1.html).
This seems to be a total mess at the moment because about 50% of the links will open Music.app and show you a beautiful white blank page. Then nothing.

Is there any way to tell if the link will be a hit without throwing users to Music.app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object isStreamable was added and it will return true or false indicating that the track is available in Apple Music or not.

Comment: isStreamable.. this is a property of what exactly?

Comment: You get it when you use the existing search API, for instance, if you search for jack johnson on it the URL will be: [link](itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson) 
isStreamable appears on the JSON result on each track.